# UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath Not Called within UITabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` within a `UIViewController`.  The `UIViewController` is both the data source and delegate for the `UICollectionView`.  Everything populates fine, and works as expected.  However, when I try and embed my UIViewController within a `UITabBarController` via the Storyboard editor, the `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method is no longer called.

Embedding the `UIViewController` within the `UITabBarController` is the ONLY change I've made.  When I remove the `UITabBarController` everything goes back to working as expected.  Has anyone else seen this type of behavior?  What am I missing that could cause this?

Comment: Are any of the other data source methods called, like numberOfItems?

Comment: Yes, numberOfItems is called and returns correctly.  It returns a value > 0, so I would assume that cellForItemAtIndexPath would be called, but it is not.

Comment: Do you know cellForItemAtIndexPath isn't called by logging, or are you assuming based on nothing showing up?

Comment: Logging, breakpoints, AND nothing is showing up.

Comment: I can't duplicate this problem when I try it, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: The UICollectionView is not the entire size of the window, so I think it is due to some sort of sizing/bounds issue.  I just can't pin it down.

Comment: That seems unlikely. There's no reason the size of the collection view would cause cellForItemAtIndexPath not to run. That being said, how are you adding it to the tab bar controller such that it's not the size of the window (or do you just mean the window size minus the tab bar)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the parent view controller's adjust scroll view insets checkbox is on. This way the UICollectionView thinks it doesn't have any visible cells and doesn't call the cellForItemAtIndexPath method. Unchecking this property will resolve the problem.
You can find it the Attributes Inspector -> View Controller / Layout section -> Adjust Scroll View Insets. 
Uncheck and voila.